# fetch data from express.js in react

Tags: reactjs, express, rest

I've been trying to fetch data from rest-api that I developed using express in react
I wrote this function to fetch data, but the data is not showing

```
  const [venues, dispatchVenues] = React.useReducer(VenueReducer, {
    data: [],
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isError: false,
  });
 


 React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatchVenues({ type: "FETCH_INIT" });
    try {
      VenueDataService.listAllVenues()
      .then((result) => {
        dispatchVenues({
          type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
          payload: result.data,
        });
       
      });
    } catch(error) {
      
      dispatchVenues({ type: "FETCH_FAILURE" });
      console.log(error);
      
    }
  }, []);
```

ı got this error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/admin' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
VenueDataService.jsx:6 
GET http://localhost:3000/api/admin net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

Comment: Search for Express and CORS - you will find plenty of solutions/discussions (hint: take a look at the package cors)

Comment: Could you share some of your api code for a clearer picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable cors in Express backend.

```
$ npm install cors
```

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```